# Find the number of objects in a json array

Tags: php, json

I have searched a lot and I found few methods to find the length of my JSON array. I have tried:

1. `count`
2. `json.length`

but these return 1, instead of the actual length. I want to show it using PHP.

My json is:

```
$huge = '[{"location":[{"building":["Default Building"],"name":"Default Location"}],"name":"Default Organization"},{"location":[{"building":["test_loc1_building1","test_loc1_building2"],"name":"test location1"},{"building":["test_loc2_building2"],"name":"test location2"}],"name":"test Organization"}]';
```

How can I find the number of objects in my JSON array?

Comment: JSON is a serialization format, what about de-serializing it and checking?

Comment: Here you have another solution without using json_decode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772904/convert-json-string-to-array-without-json-decode

Comment: Here you have another solution without using json_decode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772904/convert-json-string-to-array-without-json-decode

Answer (score 34):

You need to [decode the json](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) object and then count the elements in it ..

```
 $json_array  = json_decode($json_string, true);
 $elementCount  = count($json_array);
```

Comment: You can shorten this to one line by nesting `$elementCount  = count(json_decode($json_string, true));` If you don't need $json_array as a PHP variable elsewhere.

Comment: But that wouldn't work because it includes the brackets and quotes.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to decode into PHP arrays before you do any work with the data.

Try:

```
$hugeArray = json_decode($huge, true); // Where variable $huge holds your JSON string.

echo count($hugeArray);
```

If you need to count to a lower depth, you'll need to iterate through the array.

For example, if you want to count the number of elements in the next layer, you can do:

```
foreach ($hugeArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' - '.count($value);
}
```

However, this isn't necessarily meaningful because it depends on *what you are trying to count, what your goal is*. This block only counts the number of elements 1 layer underneath, regardless of what the actual numbers could mean.

Comment: and now how can print the number of objects in each small array

Comment: @user2201395 Then you iterate through the array's elements and echo the count() of each element.

Answer (score 0):

First decode your `json` and after that use `count` on it.

```
$huge='[{"location":[{"building":["Default Building"],"name":"Default Location"}],"name":"Default Organization"},{"location":[{"building":["test_loc1_building1","test_loc1_building2"],"name":"test location1"},{"building":["test_loc2_building2"],"name":"test location2"}],"name":"test Organization"}]';
$arr = json_decode($huge,true);
echo count($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use ".sizeof()" function.
So

Answer (score -1):

> Object (an unordered collection of key:value pairs with the ':' character separating the key and the value, comma-separated and enclosed in curly braces; ...)

[Wikipedia: JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example)

So, all you have to do are just count opened curly braces.

```
substr_count($huge , '{');
```

But... If you are storing some strings with '{' in json you can't do it. In that way you have to write your own simple parser or regular expression.

But... the easies way to json_decode. And use recursive function if you want to get count of **all** objects in json.

```
function count_objects($value)
    {
    if (is_scalar($value) || is_null($value))
        $count = 0;
    elseif (is_array($value))
        {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($value as $val)
            $count += count_objects($val);
        }
    elseif (is_object($value))
        {
        $count = 1;
        $reflection_object = new \ReflectionObject($value);
        foreach ($reflection_object->getProperties() as $property)
            {
            $count +=count_objects($property->getValue($value));
            }
        }

    return $count;
    }

$huge = '[{"location":[{"building":["Default Building"],"name":"Default Location"}],"name":"Default Organization"},{"location":[{"building":["test_loc1_building1","test_loc1_building2"],"name":"test location1"},{"building":["test_loc2_building2"],"name":"test location2"}],"name":"test Organization"}]';

echo count_objects(json_decode($huge));
```